# Carbon today or previous dates

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to restrict users from putting dates less than today using carbon and laravel 7.
My date is in the form of 02-02-2020. I keep getting this error Call to a member function lessThanOrEqualTo() on integer".

```
case 4:

                        $todayDate = Carbon::now();

                        if (strlen($parts[3]) != 8) {

                            unset($session[3]);

                            $response = "CON C4C\nEnter a valid date of contact. DDMMYYYY eg  01122020";

                        } else {

                            try {

                                $session['date_of_contact'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('dmY', $parts[3])->format('Y-m-d ');

                                $this->setSession($session);

                                $userdate = strtotime($session['date_of_contact']);

                                if($userdate->lessThanOrEqualTo($todayDate)) {

                                    unset($session[3]);

                                    $response = "CON C4C\nFuture dates are invalid";
                                }

                                $response = $this->sessionOpeningTag . "What is the source of exposure?\n1 Patient\n2 Colleague\n3 Community\n4 Home\n5 Unknown";


                            } catch (Exception $exception) {

                                $response = $this->sessionClosingTag . "You have entered an invalid date";

                                $this->deleteSession($session);

                            }
                        }    

                        break;
```

Comment: Change `$todayDate = Carbon::now();` to `$todayDate = Carbon::now()->format(Y-m-d);`

Comment: `strtotime` returns an integer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parsing string dates to Carbon objects, there is an optimistic approach.

```
$userdate = Carbon::parse($session['date_of_contact']);
```

A pessimistic approach, you would specify the format.

```
 $userdate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $session['date_of_contact']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$session['date_of_contact']->lessThanOrEqualTo(Carbon::today())
```

And get rid of `$todayDate`, `$userdate` and `strtotime`